# Comma in an if statement

Tags: javascript

I've come across a rather confusing statement in some JavaScript:

```js
if (n = "value", a==b) {...
```

I take it that this assigns the value `n` first and then performs a comparison (`a==b`) to determine whether to proceed with the `if` statement.  But why?  Is there any advantage to doing this over say...

```js
n = "value";
if (a==b) {...
```

or...

```js
if (a==b) {n = "value"; ...
```

Comment: Your third snippet is not the same as two previous snippets. In two first snippets `n` is set in any case, in the third snippet `n` will be set only if `if` passes.

Comment: Hmm. That's true.  What I was getting at, I suppose, is whether the scope of `n` is restricted in anyway by delcaring it in the `if` function (succinctly answered by Danilo below).  In theory if `n` was restricted to the scope of the `if` statement then it could be available to the final comparison, so even if the test fails `n` gets its value for the scope of `if`.

Comment: @Question participants: (I know it's bad form on SO :-O ) but many thanks to you all for helping me understand this.  I have actually used this now and found it makes the code *more* readable (in my current case) than less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, whenever you put more than one expression inside a pair of brackets, they are evaluated as the last expression, like in the example below:

```
var a = (1, 2);
var b = a + 1;    // b = 2 + 1 = 3
```

So, in your case, the interpreter executes the attribution `n = "value"` and then parses the if taking `a == b` as condition. It's the same as:

```
n = "value";
if (a == b) {
    // ...
}
```

[This article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/) explains this behaviour.

## **EDIT**

However, this does not limit `n` to the `if`'s scope. This same thing happens to var declarations in `for` loops:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Do stuff...
}
console.log(i);    // Logs 10
```

---

## **EDIT 2**

As Ethan Brown mentioned, is also good to tell about variable hoisting, which is basically the fact that, in JavaScript, values can be assigned to variables before declaring them. The  following code shows this behaviour and was extracted from [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting):

```
bla = 2
var bla;

// The above code is valid, since
// it's implicitly understood as:

var bla;
bla = 2;
```

The same occurs with functions:

```
foo();
function foo() {
    console.log('bar');
}
```

Comment: So is the scope of `n` limited to the `if` statement?

Comment: Nice job mentioning variable scope, but you should probably discuss or point to a resource on "variable hoisting", which is necessary to really understand variable scope in JS.

Comment: So just referring to **EDIT 2**, is this good practice or just accepted?  And would `bla = 2; var x = bla * 2; var bla;` be valid (i.e. `bla` is not only assigned but also used before it is declared)?

Comment: Yes, it's valid and works fine. However, I don't consider this being a good practice because, unless strictly necessary, it makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: Yep - that's what I thought. Many thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your assessment of the meaning is correct.  There is no advantage other than compactness.  Many would consider this poor practice, but it doesn't bother me.

Where it gets tricky is when you start calling functions that have side effects...then you can do some really weird stuff.

Comment: Heh.  Happens more often than you might think.  `var x=0; function doSomething(){x++;}; if(doSomething(), x===3){/*..*/}`

Comment: Yep - I'm now the proud new owner of this statement: `if (fail = sel.selectedIndex == 0, fail) break;`

Comment: Now see that's just silly...the assignment operator returns the assigned value, so that's equivalent to just saying `if((fail = sel.selectedIndex) == 0)`.

Comment: No, it isn't - the comparison of `sel.selectedIndex == 0` is assigned to `fail` for later use in the same script then `fail` is also used as the second half of the comma operator. But perhaps it could do with brackets around the comparison, so maybe it should be `if (fail = (sel.selectedIndex == 0), fail) break;`

Comment: Ah, right you are, Westie.  I was thinking about what I thought you were *trying* to do, not what the statement was *actually* saying.

Answer (score 0):

You're right - it's just a really confusing way to phrase assigning a variable and then running an `if` statement. It's valid code, but equivalent to the less puzzling version, so this is most likely just a case of someone being too clever.

Comment: A frequent issue in our field of work . . . people who think that, because they learn/discover a rarely known way of doing something, that makes it a good way to do it.

Comment: @talemyn: I prefer to know what I'm doing before I actually use such constructs!

Comment: @Westie - and that puts you a step above a lot of your peers!   :D

Comment: @tmcw: I must say that I've found that it can make code *more* readable! In the example that I've commented above in Ehtan's answer (`if (fail = sel.selectedIndex == 0, fail) break;`) the assignment to `fail` becomes contextual to the `if` statement.  It's a beautiful, elegant thing!